# Type guard with other variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

is it possible for an other variable to function as type guard?

assume some code like this

```js
let foo: string | null = Math.random() > .5 ? null : 'bar'
const otherProp = true
const test = foo !== null && otherProp
function foobar(x: string){}
```

if i would now call `foobar(foo)` i assume a warning as foo can be null or string and only string is allowed

but if i call it like

```js
if (test){
    foobar(foo)
}
```

it should not warn me as test is only true if foo is not null and so only string remains as type

is something like this possible?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAZg9jBcEDOYBOBLAdgcwgHwkwFdhgIBeCAWQEMwALAOlRswBMYBbACgEoIAfBEYBWCAH5CJMogDkAIxqpZAWABQAYxiYUEGAxCoACqhgAHChDREQ6rTshgQuyrBgQAhOUrFSEAGT%20egbGpmbqUESYGmDo2tBwiqjcAB6IKBg4vADeAL7q6gD0hcj0MCRsEIamqBGJStxuvAVqxaXlwJWY%20lWoNeroUBDcTig56hCTCTBJjXDNavlq6kA)

Comment: Typescript would understand it if you put the `foo !== null` check directly into the if statement. Is there a reason you are not doing this?

Comment: yes. helps readability. in my production code the if part is on a couple of places i would like to not inline it on all places

Comment: You can use a custom type guard `isNotNull = <T>(x:T): x is Exclude(T, null) => x !== null` which is then easily reusable `if (isNotNull(foo))`

Comment: @VLAZ that would mean i need to call a function in every if and could not precompute it once. so this means more computation just to make TS happy seems not a good choice

Comment: @L.A yes, having a function will make it so you have to re-evaluate it every time. However, let's look at the flip side - if you compute once and want to use the cached result, you now have non-reusable code. If you need to make the same check in a different scope, then you have to repeat the check. You have to extract it into (effectively) a type guard anyway to reuse it. Assuming your type guard does a trivial operation like a null check or a property lookup, it's not going to have a performance impact. You can still memoize the guard if it's REALLY expensive.

Comment: @VLAZ you are totally right. i assume its just a pity that i need to jump threw hoops to make ts happy. I would like to use the variable option just pure from a readability standpoint feels just cleaner for me. but seems like TS doesn't provide this currently. so i assume your type guard function is a way to do it sure. feels just not as clean for me

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in TS right now. because it adds considerable complexity to their Control-Flow Analyzer. other than explicitly putting `foo !== null` as the `if expression`, there two possible things to do:

1- using [Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
if (test){
    // since test is equal to (foo !== null)
    foobar(foo as string)
}
```

But it's a bit bug-prone because you may change the `test` variable in the future then that type assertion would lead to bugs because foo is no longer for sure a `string`.

2- [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

The better way in my opinion is using user-defined type guard as @VLAZ correctly mentioned.

```
   const isNotNull = <T>(x:T): x is Exclude(T, null) => x !== null
    
   if (isNotNull(foo)){
     foobar(foo)
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible (see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184)).

Here's a workaround. It assigns `wrappedFoo` a type which either contains a string and true, or null and false. After checking for the boolean value, Typescript knows which of those two it is:

```js
const foo: string | null = Math.random() > .5 ? null : 'bar'
const wrappedFoo = foo === null ? { foo, isString: false as const } : { foo, isString: true as const }

if (wrappedFoo.isString){
    console.log(wrappedFoo.foo.length)
} else {
    console.log(wrappedFoo.foo.length) // Error Object is possibly 'null'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Next version of Typescript (4.4) [will support control flow analysis of conditional expressions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730). The only change you'll need to do is `let foo` -> `const foo`, because

> Narrowing through indirect references occurs only when the conditional expression or discriminant property access is declared in a `const` variable declaration with no type annotation, and the reference being narrowed is a const variable, a readonly property, or a parameter for which there are no assignments in the function body

[Playground v4.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-dev.20210702#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MCyBDKALAdAJwzABMQBbACgEoYA%20GXAVhgH4YwBXAGy5gC4YAcgBGGfIICwAKFCRYIHAFN8ABXwgADihhR8HRdNnQdi46gRIAhMlSceMAGQOYC7MrWbpcDmGBQAluDwiKL4FAAeAtD4-mAA5jQA3jAAvtLSAPQZMBDYINzEMMrq%20F4hYhQWVOlSWTl5BewKRfgl0v5wMBRQplBJ0jCDwSChlYjVUilAA)